# Como implementar ajax si trabajo con multiples archivos

Tags: php, ajax

Tengo esta interfaz https://i.stack.imgur.com/SWEsY.jpg y quiero que cuando el usuario inserte, elimine o modifique algo, la tabla se refresque sin necesidad de actualizar. Pero cuando le doy clic a algun boton me redirecciona al archivo `insertar.php` o `modificar.php` segun sea el caso. No tengo todo el código en un solo archivo por que es muy extenso de por si.

¿Como puedo implementar ajax en esta interfaz?

Anexo el codigo del form a continuacion. Cualquier cosa que necesiten me lo dejan saber.

```
<form   method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" >

                        <input type="hidden" name="id_playera" id="id_playera"><br>
                        Nombre:<br>
                        <input type="text" name="nombre_playera" id="nombre_playera" size="35" placeholder="Escribe el nombre de la playera" required="required"><br>
                        Precio:<br>
                        <input type="number" name="precio_playera" id="precio_playera" min="1" size="35" placeholder="Escribe el precio de la playera" required="required"><br>
                        Color:<br>
                        <input type="text" name="color_playera" id="color_playera" size="35" placeholder="Escribe el color de la playera" required="required"><br>
                         Chica:<br>
                        <input type="number" name="talla_chica" id="talla_chica" min="0"  step="1" size="35" placeholder="Escribe la cantidad chica" required="required"><br>
                         Mediana:<br>
                        <input type="number" name="talla_mediana" id="talla_mediana" min="0" step="1" size="35" placeholder="Escribe la cantidad mediana" required="required"><br>
                         Grande:<br>
                        <input type="number" name="talla_grande" id="talla_grande" min="0"  step="1" size="35" placeholder="Escribe la cantidad grande " required="required"><br>
                         Extra grande:<br>
                        <input type="number" name="talla_egrande" id="talla_egrande" min="0"  step="1" size="40" placeholder="Escribe la cantidad de extra grande" required="required">
                        <img id="imgPlayera" src="#" alt="your image" style="margin-left: 400px" /><br>
                         <input type='file' name="nombreArchvio" id="btnimgplayera" onchange="readURL(this);" value= "Escoge una imagen" style="margin-left: 500px; margin-top-280px" required="required"/>
                        <input type="hidden" name="imagen_playera" id="imagen_playera"> 

                    Descripcion:<br>
                    <textarea type="text" rows="4" cols="50" name="descripcion_playera" id="descripcion_playera" maxlength="200" required="required" placeholder="Escibre una descripciÃ³n del producto (Max 200 caracteres)"></textarea><br>

                <input type="submit" onclick="myFunction()" formaction="insertar_playera.php" name="btninsertar" value="insertar" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
<script>
function myFunction() {
    alert("Se ha agregado el producto correctamente");
}
</script>
                <input type="submit" formaction="modificar_playera.php" name="btnmodificar" value="modificar">
                <input type="submit" formaction="eliminar_playera.php" name="button" value="eliminar">
                </form>
                <br>
                <input type="text" id="busca_playera" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Buscar playera..">
```

insertar playera.php

```
<?php
$conexion = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "12345678");
if (!$conexion) {
    echo "No pudo conectarse a la BD: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}

if (!mysql_select_db("metalstorm")) {
    echo "No ha sido posible seleccionar la BD: " . mysql_error();
    exit;
}


if(isset($_POST['btninsertar']))
{
    $fileName = $_FILES['nombreArchvio']['name'];
    $tempName = $_FILES['nombreArchvio']['tmp_name'];
        if(isset($fileName))
    {

        echo "Nombre temporal".$tempName."<br>";
        echo "Nombre del arcv".$fileName."<br>";


        echo $tempName;
        echo $fileName;


                if(!empty($fileName))
        {
            $location = "productos/playeras/";
            if(move_uploaded_file($tempName, $location.$fileName))
            {

$nombre_playera=$_POST['nombre_playera'];
$precio_playera=$_POST['precio_playera'];
$color_playera=$_POST['color_playera'];
$talla_chica=$_POST['talla_chica'];
$talla_mediana=$_POST['talla_mediana'];
$talla_grande=$_POST['talla_grande'];
$talla_egrande=$_POST['talla_egrande'];
$descripcion=$_POST['descripcion_playera'];
$imagen=$_POST['imagen_playera'];
$sql = "INSERT into playeras ( nombre, precio, color, chica, mediana, grande, extra_grande, descripcion, imagen)
 VALUES ('$nombre_playera','$precio_playera', '$color_playera', '$talla_chica', '$talla_mediana','$talla_grande','$talla_egrande', '$descripcion', '$fileName') ";

$resultado = mysql_query($sql);



if (!$resultado) {
    echo "No se pudo ejecutar con exito la consulta ($sql) en la BD: " . mysql_error();

}else{
    echo "dato insertado exitosamente";
}
                echo 'Copia exitosa';
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hombre, si fuera tu, separaría el tema busquedas de las inserciones, son acciones distintas, por lo que deberías meterlo en forms distintos, para así trabajar mejor con ello. (y el script no lo pongas en mitad del html, en la carga interrumpe el flujo de carga, o algo así, ponlo simpre que puedas en el head, o si no al final de todo el html). Una vez tengas separado los formularios, con ajax puedes mandar el resultado del primero (insertar) y que la respuesta que reciba añadirla a tu tabla.

Answer (score 0):

Deberías asignar una llamada vía Ajax a cada uno de los php para insertar, modificar, eliminar en los botones correspondientes.

Además deberías tener otro PHP que se encargase de "pintar" la tabla inferior cuando se actualice algo.

Para ello deberías de cambiar los inputs tal que así:

```
<input type="button" id="btninsertar" value="insertar">
```

Ponerle un id al form para poder enviar sus valores mediante Ajax al php correspondiente, además de quitarle el method para que no envie nada.

```
<form id='frm' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Te pongo código para jQuery por lo que deberías añadir la librería en el html tal que así, o te descargas el fichero js y lo metes con tu código:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Ahora necesitarás para cada botón un código similar a este:

```
$('#btnInsertar').on('click', function() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'insertar_playera.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: 'text',
        data: $('#frm').serialize(),
        error: function(){
            alert("Error al insertar playera");
        }
    }).done( function(ret) {
       if ( ret == 'OK' ) {
          actualizarTabla();
       } else {
          alert( ret );
       }
    });
});
```

El php insertar_playera.php recibirá por POST todos los campos del formulario con el nombre que tenga cada elemento en el atributo `name`. Te he configurado para que el php que tienes que hacer devuelva texto plano (text), debería devolver el texto `OK` en caso de insertarse correctamente o cualquier otro texto en caso de error. Eso se detecta en la parte del done, y muestra el error o actualiza la tabla inferior.

Lo mismo que tienes aquí para el botón insertar deberías de hacerlo para el resto de los inputs, tendrías que añadir un código similar al anterior para cada botón, llamando al php correspondiente, .....

La funcion actualizarTabla es la que llamará al php que generará el código HTML de la tabla inferior. Dicha tabla la colocaría dentro de un `<div id='tabla'>` para así poder cambiar el contenido de la tabla con la salida del php.

```
function actualizarTabla() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'listar_playeras.php',
        dataType: 'html',
        error: function(){
            alert("Error al listas las playeras");
        }
    }).done( function(ret) {
        $("#tabla").html(ret);    
    });
}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda hice exactamente lo que me dijiste y no me inserta no se por que :/ anexe el codigo de insertar_playera por aquello de que se necesite, en este codigo tambien copio la imagen que se selecciono a una carpeta solo para que sepas que onda jeje

Comment: Si hiciste los pasos que te indique `btninsertar` ya no existirá y por eso no te inserta. Piensa que ahora como cada botón lleva su código asociado y por lo tanto no hay que detectar que botón submit es el que pulsó el usuario.